# Scrapy result nesting not as it should be

Tags: xml, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to crawl a webpage, and when i get the results in xml they are not nested as it should be, or at least not as i was expecting them to be.

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)
    titles = hxs.xpath("//div[@class='teaserarticles']")
    items = []
    for titles in titles:
        item = CraigslistSampleItem()
        item ["title"] = titles.select("..//div[@class='headline']/h1/a/text()").extract()
        item ["link"] = titles.select(".//div[@class='headline']/h1/a/@href").extract()
        item ["photo"] = titles.select(".//div[@class='article-img']/img/@src").extract()
        item ["desc"] = titles.select(".//div[@class='item-bg']/p/text()").extract()
        items.append(item)
        return items
```

I get the values that i need t get but i get them in the format:

```
<item>
        <photo>
            <value>/images/resized/images/stories/2015/09/10/suvenirnica1-160_160_100.jpg</value>
            <value>/images/resized/images/stories/2015/09/09/azilantiiii_160_100.jpg</value>
            <value>/images/resized/images/stories/2015/09/09/dzeriiiiii__160_100.jpg</value>
        </photo>
```

and they should bi like:

```
  <photo>
        <value>/images/resized/images/stories/2015/09/10/suvenirnica1-160_160_100.jpg</value>
  </photo>
  <photo>
        <value>/images/resized/images/stories/2015/09/09/azilantiiii_160_100.jpg</value>
  </photo>
  <photo>
        <value>/images/resized/images/stories/2015/09/09/dzeriiiiii__160_100.jpg</value>
</photo>
</photo>
```

Comment: The first part of your code (showing the parse method), parses content into a series of items.  These items are then returned to be processed by a pipeline, which I assume is saving them to XML.  However, you didn't provide the pipeline code.  Nowhere in the code you provided would XML be generated.

Comment: i use the scrapy crawl 'name' -o list.xml to export it in xml